# Pass the variable to curl command to inovoke rest api url n python

Tags: python

I am trying to pass the report title name using a variable triggername. When I execute the code, I am value of the triggername is not captured in the api url.

Can someone help me to fix this?

```
**#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import requests
import os
import commands
triggername="GSD_Trigger_Active"
print("**********",triggername, type(triggername))
cmd="""curl -v -u $(ops_unv_cred_user_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc):$(ops_unv_cred_pwd_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc)  -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET 'https://xxxxx.cloud/resources/report/run?reporttitle=triggername'
"""
os.system(cmd)
```

I am getting the below error message:

```
Could not find report with name "triggername"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you need to interpolate the variable. The most simplest way is this.

```
triggername = "GSD_Trigger_Active"
cmd= f'curl -v -u $(ops_unv_cred_user_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc):$(ops_unv_cred_pwd_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc)  -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "https://xxxxx.cloud/resources/report/run?reporttitle={triggername}"'
```

This should give you the cmd as 
`'curl -v -u $(ops_unv_cred_user_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc):$(ops_unv_cred_pwd_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc)  -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "https://xxxxx.cloud/resources/report/run?reporttitle=GSD_Trigger_Active"'`

Adding Screenshot:

[image: PyShell]

Prior to `python3.6` use this:

```
cmd = 'curl -v -u $(ops_unv_cred_user_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc):$(ops_unv_cred_pwd_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc)  -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "https://xxxxx.cloud/resources/report/run?reporttitle={}"'.format(triggername)
```

Comment: I need to run multiple reports based on the if condition.So i use the above code, i have to duplicate the code for each report. Adding to it, there few more lines i need to add after executing the above code.I am planning to define a function to put all these codes, but it would only when i pass the report name through variable. Could you make   any other suggestions.

Comment: No matter you design, what you need is interpolation. I've given u an  example for this. How to remove duplicates and making it more efficient/clean  is upto u now.

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately i am getting syntax error..           cmd = f'curl -v -u $(ops_unv_cred_user_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc):$(ops_unv_cred_pwd_35ab1e1285be4e659f9ab15fca0a35fc)  -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "https://bptest.stonebranch.cloud/resources/report/run?reporttitle={triggername}"'

Comment: Not sure if i am missing any braces or quotation.

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact error message you are getting. Or post a screenshot of it.

Comment: I have added a screenshot that shows no problem with the code in the answer

Comment: Strings starting with `f'` (called "f-strings") are only available since Python 3.6, so if you're using an older version, they won't work.

Comment: Added a way to interpolate if you are using a version prior to `python3.6`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suppport, it works now as expected. I was trying the in the older version..